# Installation Error:Unknown Failure-while running on real device android lollipop 5.0

Tags: android, debugging

When I run my android project in real devide (Asus ZenFone 4 ,android 5.0).Eclipse show me this error .
[image: I get this error]

But when I run this project in Emulator(SamSung Galaxy S3,HTC EVO...) .It run ok.

I tried to look on the internet without success.Please help me.

Comment: Can you add the logcat?

Comment: show logcat  details..

Comment: make sure that you enabled debugging mode in the device

Comment: I enabled debugging mode in the device in my device ! .I tried to uncheck Verify apps over USB (Developer Opption) it can run .But  sometimes it does not run again @ SaNtoRiaN

Answer (score 0):

In device manager of Windows, please check how your device is recognized.
It is correct if your device is recognized as "Android Composite ADB Interface" under Android Device. In my case, my device was "ASUS Android Composite ADB Interface". There was a prefix "ASUS". This interface was very unstable. Therefore, I deleted this driver, and reinstalled "Android Composite ADB Interface" which does not have a prefix "ASUS". Then, no errors appeared in my case.